# Why tkinter canvas xview_moveto() does not work properly?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make movement of the canvas automatic, i.e. moving plot along with charts drawn on the canvas, for that I'm using xview_moveto() function, but for some reason it only moves canvas 1 time, the second time view returns to initial view, do not know why, could some one help to understand?

here is part of my code:

```
enter code here

x_cord = 0
y_cord = 0
x0_cord = 50
y0_cord = 850
x2_cord = 1800
trig_1 = 0
def send_com(com1):
    ......
    ........
    .........
    if var1.find('A54_')>=1:
        first = var1.find('A54_')
        a_val = var1[first+4: first+8]
        alanog_val = int(a_val)*100/1023     
        barA0['value'] = alanog_val

        b_val = int(a_val)/1.204
        global x0_cord
        global y0_cord
        global x2_cord
        x_cord = x0_cord + 100
        y_cord = 850 - b_val
        canv.create_line(x0_cord, y0_cord, x_cord, y_cord,  width=2, 
smooth = "true", activefill = "blue", fill="red")
        #canv.create_text(x_cord, y_cord, text="A0",  anchor=tk.SE, 
font='bold', activefill = "blue", fill="red")
        #print(x0_cord, y0_cord, x_cord, y_cord)
        x0_cord = x_cord
        y0_cord = y_cord
        if x_cord > x2_cord:
            canv.config(scrollregion=( x2_cord , 0,1800,0))
            canv.create_line(50,850,x2_cord+1800,850,width=2,arrow=LAST)
            canv.after(500, canv.xview_moveto,x2_cord)
            x2_cord = x2_cord + 1800
```

Comment: add tag `python` and it will highlight code.

Answer (score 0):

The method `xview_moveto` takes a fraction between zero and one. Anything larger than one will be treated as one. From the canonical tcl/tk documentation:

> Adjusts the view in the window so that fraction of the total width of the canvas is off-screen to the left. Fraction must be a fraction between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks for comments @Bryan, how to adjust the view, that was my question if not using xview_move to method? I've tried so many things, but have not succeed so far, what do you mean by adjusting the view so that fraction of the total width is equals to 1? I have added the following line to increase canvas size: <code>canv.config(width = x2_cord)</code> ,  but <code> canv.xview_moveto(x2_cord)</code> still returns me to the beginning of the canvas, where fraction of the canvas to the moveto position is equals to 1 as you proposed... What method to use to adjust the view?

Comment: @Brian Oakley thanks, got you bud, the method canv.xview(SCROLL, 1, 'page') worked out for me!